# LINQ left join throwing System.NullReferenceException or System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to create a LINQ statement that will join two tables with a left outer join.

The code below gets a `DataTable` (containing Active Directory usernames) of people who work for the logged in user, gets another `DataTable` which is a cross-reference between AD username and an application login name, and then joins them to create a `List<string>` containing either the application login name (if present) else the AD username, for every person who works for the logged in user.

The `NullReferenceException` error occurs (on the `select new` line) when the list of Logins does not contain anybody in the list of Subordinates.

The `InvalidCastException` error occurs (on the `return result...` line) when the list of Logins does contain somebody who is in the list of Subordinates.  The full error here is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'

```
TMReportsDataSet.EmployeeDataTable subordinates = SessionTyped.Subordinates;
TMReportsDataSet.EmployeeLoginDataTable logins = CacheTyped.Logins;

var result = from t1 in subordinates.AsEnumerable()
             join t2 in logins.AsEnumerable()
             on t1.ADAccountName equals t2.ADAccountName
             into joinedDT
             from t2 in joinedDT.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 userName = (string)(t2.LoginName ?? t1.ADAccountName)
             };

return result.Cast<string>().ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to cast an anonymous type to a string. Remove the use of the anonymous type as follows:

```
var result = from t1 in subordinates.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in logins.AsEnumerable()
                 on t1.ADAccountName equals t2.ADAccountName
                 into joinedDT
                 from t2 in joinedDT.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select (string)(t2.LoginName ?? t1.ADAccountName);

return result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thankyou, that has resolved the InvalidCastException nicely.  And because that exception is fixed, my attempted solution for the NullReferenceException exception (to check whether t2 is null) now also works correctly.  I'll edit your answer to also include that fix.

Answer (score 2):

As my edit of Magnus' answer was rejected [I don't understand why?] here is the full answer to my question, which is essentially the answer Magnus gave but with an additional check to see if `t2 == null` to avoid getting `NullReferenceException` errors.

```
var result = from t1 in subordinates.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in logins.AsEnumerable()
                 on t1.ADAccountName equals t2.ADAccountName
                 into joinedDT
                 from t2 in joinedDT.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select (string)(t2 == null ? "" : (t2.LoginName ?? t1.ADAccountName));

return result.ToList();
```